# using array of custom NSManagedObject in another NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

I have a "Record" `NSManagedObject` class and "Title" `NSManagedObject`,

Record object have 2 properties, title and `laTitle` both are of type "Title" ManagedObject.

and also need this "Title" object as other `NSManagedObjects` which have no relation to the "Record" object, so I can't use relationship as "title" is independant of "Record" object.

Do I have any other way than saving the Title Object as "Binary data" in Record Object and other Objects. Something like having to-many relationship without inverse relationship.

Comment: why you can not use title object as relation

Comment: @SunilPandey : because "Title" object belongs to other entities too.
consider Feed as another object,

like Record -> Title, Feed -> Title, then If I use relation, Title will have two relation object "Record" and "Feed" , and one of them will be nil always which doesn't seem to be a good model for me.